# Partial-Sign Transaction from Front-end

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

Is it anyhow possible to apartial sign a transaction from client side and send it back to server side for final sign and sending to blockchain?

Answer (score 7):

I think Elliot's answer can be accepted, but I want to add some clarifying comments, and it's easier to read these as a separate answer.

`partialSign` is an API of the web3.js `Transaction` object, but **not** the new `VersionedTransaction` object, which has only a `sign` method. This means it won't be used at all if you're using `VersionedTransaction` (or the wallet uses it internally). If you look at the implementation of `partialSign`, you will see that all it's doing is signing the transaction, without verifying the signatures (which `Transaction::sign` does). Some wallets call `partialSign` internally, others just create the cryptographic signature and call `Transaction::addSignature`.

`signTransaction` is an API of Wallet Adapter. This is what you want to use to sign a transaction without sending it. How wallets implement this is out of scope for Wallet Adapter, and more importantly, cannot be determined by Wallet Adapter (e.g. whether they use `partialSign`, `addSignature`, directly manipulate the `signatures` array, or something else). Wallet Adapter sends a `Transaction` in (maybe with some signatures on it), and gets a `Transaction` out (hopefully with more signatures on it).

`Transaction` should never have had two methods for this, because signing and verification of signatures should never have been bundled together. This is why the newer `VersionedTransaction` implementation does not have two methods for signing. Wallet Adapter (and the `solana:` features of the Wallet Standard) will not implement a `partialSign` API, because from its perspective, *all* signing should be regarded as "partial". All wallets should correctly implement multiple signatures because Solana's transaction format allows and expects them.

The "workaround" is to get wallets to fix their implementations. If you're encountering wallets that incorrectly handle multiple expected signatures, please take it up with them, and let me know who they are, so I can pester them about it. :)

Answer (score 6):

At the time of writing this, there isn't a one-size fits all solution to do this. In testing, you can do as Swaroop suggested, but in the real world you'll likely only have access to the user's private key abstracted away by a walletadapter interface.

If you look inside the walletadapter interface, at the time of this writing, it only specifies a [`signTransaction` and `signAllTransactions`](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/packages/core/base/src/signer.ts#L85) *interface* that wallets have to implement, but it does not specify a method by which to partial sign at the moment. Since it is an interface however, it is not unlikely that some wallets actually do support partial signing in the actual implementation.

So what can you concretely do?

1. Jordan, the maintainer of the wallet adapter [repo](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter), is very active and helpful. If you think partial signing is an important feature, I suggest you open an issue/PR suggesting/implementing it.
2. In the meantime, you can parse through the different wallet adapter implementations of the wallet adapter by different wallets which you can find in `packages/wallets/<walletName>` for each wallet ([here is the link for Solflare to get you started](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/tree/master/packages/wallets/solflare)) and then do a check for the wallet type in your app that throws an error if the wallet does not support partial signing (I trust in your ability to serialize & parse the transaction once it's partially signed ;)).

Comment: I'm aware the temporary workaround `2.` is a major pain in the bum, but I wanted to suggest something as I hate stackexchange answers that just say "You can't"

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! Appreciate it. I've opened an issue in the wallet-adapter repo to see if anyone can possibly see it as a need of implementation and implements it in near future.

Comment: See https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/5030/364 but Elliot's answer is good :)

Answer (score -2):

You can partially sign your transaction and send it to the server as a base64 encoded string.

Steps:

1. Sign the transaction partially.
2. Then encode it as a string and send
   it to the server.
3. Deserialize the transaction on the server and sign
   it with the remaining keys.
4. Execute the transaction.

#### Client Side

```
transaction.partialSign(mint);
const encoded = base64.encode(transaction.serialize());
```

#### Server Side

```
const transactionBuf = Buffer.from(serializedTransaction, 'base64')
var transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(transactionBuf);
```

Comment: How do I go with asking the user for approval of the transaction in that case?

Comment: You have to decode the transaction in frontend and do wallet.signTransaction(transaction) from the wallet-adapter-package to sign the tx by the user and then you can use the sendTransaction method to send it to the blockchain