# Partially sign a VersionedTransaction in Rust

Tags: rust, solana-sdk, versionedtransactions

What's the recommended way to partially sign a VersionedTransaction in Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized you can achieve partial signing via `NullSigner`:

```
use bincode::{deserialize, serialize};
use solana_sdk::{
    instruction::{AccountMeta, Instruction},
    message::{Message as LegacyMessage, VersionedMessage},
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    signer::{keypair::Keypair, null_signer::NullSigner, Signer},
    transaction::VersionedTransaction,
};

let keypair0 = Keypair::new();
let keypair1 = Keypair::new();

let message = VersionedMessage::Legacy(LegacyMessage::new(
    &[Instruction::new_with_bytes(
        Pubkey::new_unique(),
        &[],
        vec![
            AccountMeta::new_readonly(keypair1.pubkey(), true),
        ],
    )],
    Some(&keypair0.pubkey()),
));
let signers: [&dyn Signer; 2] = [&keypair0, &NullSigner::new(&keypair1.pubkey())];
let partially_signed = VersionedTransaction::try_new(message.clone(), &signers).unwrap();
```

Then suppose you serialize this partially signed transaction and send it to your friend who needs to sign with their pubkey. They need to deserialize it, find the index of `tx.signatures` where their signature should be, and replace `Signature::default()` with their signature:

```
let serialized = serialize(&partially_signed).unwrap();
let mut deserialized: VersionedTransaction = deserialize(&serialized).unwrap();
assert_eq!(deserialized, partially_signed);
let deserialized_message = &deserialized.message;
let keypair1_sig_index = deserialized_message
    .static_account_keys()
    .iter()
    .position(|key| key == &keypair1.pubkey())
    .unwrap();
deserialized.signatures[keypair1_sig_index] =
    keypair1.sign_message(&deserialized_message.serialize());
```

Please chime in if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

From the answer of this question: [Partial-Sign Transaction from Front-end](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5007/partial-sign-transaction-from-front-end)

> partialSign is an API of the web3.js Transaction object, but not the
> new VersionedTransaction object, which has only a sign method. This
> means it won't be used at all if you're using VersionedTransaction (or
> the wallet uses it internally). If you look at the implementation of
> partialSign, you will see that all it's doing is signing the
> transaction, without verifying the signatures (which Transaction::sign
> does). Some wallets call partialSign internally, others just create
> the cryptographic signature and call Transaction::addSignature.
>
> Transaction should never have had two methods for this, because
> signing and verification of signatures should never have been bundled
> together. This is why the newer VersionedTransaction implementation
> does not have two methods for signing. Wallet Adapter (and the solana:
> features of the Wallet Standard) will not implement a partialSign API,
> because from its perspective, all signing should be regarded as
> "partial". All wallets should correctly implement multiple signatures
> because Solana's transaction format allows and expects them